# Is it possible to extract parts of a string and replace those parts in one operation in Golang?

Tags: regex, performance, go

Say I want to extract all numbers from a string (Most likely using regex matching) and I also want to replace those number matches with a generic placeholder like "#".

This is easily done in two parts using FindAll, then ReplaceAll. However I have serious doubts about the performance costs of doing such operations.

So take a string

```
"sdasd 3.2% sadas 6 ... +8.9"
```

replace it with

```
"sdasd #% sadas # ... +#"
```

and get a slice

```
[3.2,6.0,8.9]
```

In the most performant way possible.

Edit : I implemented the regexp.FindAllString + regexp.ReplaceAllString and the performance hit to my app was very minimal. I will hopefully try Elliot Chance's approach and compare the two when I have time.

Comment: The fact that it takes two function calls does not necessarily imply that it performs poorly.  Line count != performance.  In this case, such a function would still have to do both, finding each item and then replacing it.  If you really want it to be a single line, though, you could extract the values out within an enclosure handed to https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.ReplaceAllFunc.  Pretty sure it would actually be *less* efficient to do it that way, though.

Comment: I agree with your sentiment @Kaedys, but regexp in general for string processing is convenient, but often horrible overkill, especially if performance is a primary concern. But yes, performance and LOC can often be completely uncorrelated.

Comment: @Kaedys I agree completely that line count has nothing to do with performance. I was simply assuming that having those two regex call would loop through each string twice, and was inquiring if it could be done in one iteration, in what I would assume would be a performance gain.

Comment: I think some have found a way to do it in one go https://elliot.silvrback.com/go-replace-string-with-regular-expression-callback

Answer (score 1):

If you need raw performance than regexp is rarely the way to achieve it, even if it is convenient. Iterating token by token should be pretty fast. Some code:

```
input := "sdasd 3.2 sadas 6"
output := []string{}
numbers := []float64{}

for _, tok := range strings.Split(input, " ") {
    if f, err := strconv.ParseFloat(tok, 64); err == nil {
        numbers = append(numbers, f)
        tok = "#"
    }
    output = append(output, tok)
}
finalString := strings.Join(output, " ")
fmt.Println(finalString, numbers)
```

[playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/8ZjljACahn)

I'm sure there's a few more optimizations in there that could be made, but this is the general approach I'd take.

Comment: That sounds elegant and simple, honestly I didn't expect calling ParseFloat on every word to be performant at all, but I'll try it out and see. I was assuming that regex matching was efficient as long as the pattern was pre-compiled beforehand, but it seems I was wrong.

Comment: Yeah, that's a concern. But if it is not something that looks like a number, ParseFloat is pretty fast. Just looks at enough characters to know it isn't a number and then returns.

Comment: https://golang.org/src/strconv/atof.go?s=11079:11134#L477 is actually kinda interesting to read through.

Comment: When in doubt, run benchmarks. I'd bet this would easily beat regexp, but I've also been pretty surprised by things in the past.

Comment: Sadly after testing with my data, splitting on " " doesnt cover everything... some numbers have a '%', '+' or '-' attached to them. It wasn't clear in my question, sorry. It was the main reason why I was looking into regex in the first place.

Comment: I see. Still, anytime I feel like regex is the solution to my problem, I make sure to ask if a simple for loop could also solve it.

Comment: It could possibly still work if before parsing to float I check the last byte to see if its % then remove it, same with if the first byte is '+'. I think '-' should already get parsed correctly. Sadly the strings.Split returns a string token so I'd have to parse it to []byte...

Answer (score 0):

Never underestimate the power of regex, especially the RE2 engine of Go.

Also, never, ever, assume anything about performance without benchmarking.  It always surprises.

The regular expression is usually compiled and cached.  To be sure, you could optimize by compiling it first.